# Magnetic potential and magnetic field assumptions

Tags: electromagnetism, calculus, magnetostatics

I've seen many proofs where you want to find the magnetic field inside and outside a solenoid for example. The author said using symmetry magnetic potential is a function of some variables and discard some variables. Also some components are made zero without solving them. 
Can someone tell me some good book where all these important peace of information are given on how to make these assumptions.

Comment: Just look up the formula in _any_ physics book. Write down the integral for  the component which ought to be zero. You will see that the integral will be symmetric and therefore will vanish.

Comment: I mean without doing the Math they make proper guesswork like A is a function of r and θ but not Φ. How do I make that guesswork?

Answer (score 0):

I guess an example helps: So let's assume a circle  of radius $R_0$ in the $xy$ plane (at the origin) carrying the current $I$. Now calculate the B-field at some point $(x, y, z)$. Using spherical coordinates, I would argue that the azimuthal component vanishes, $B_\varphi=0$, due to symmetry.

Without doing the calculation I picture the magnetic field lines "coming out" of the loop and deduce, that there can't be an azimuthal component. However, if somebody disagrees with this statement, I would have to convince him/her by doing the calculation -- or rather let him/her do it.

One could start with Biot-Savart's law, but since we are only interested in the symmetry, it probably is better to start with the equation describing the vector potential, $$\textbf{A} \propto \int dV^\prime\; \frac{\textbf{j}(\textbf{r}^\prime)}{|\textbf{r} - \textbf{r}^\prime|}$$
We would find that $\textbf{A} = A_\varphi \textbf{e}_\varphi$. The calculation is done [here](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/jk1/lectures/node52.html).

Now you could calc the B-field 
$$\textbf{B} = \nabla \times \textbf{A}$$
To see that the azimuthal component vanishes, just express the curl in spherical coordinates, $$B_\varphi = \frac{1}{r} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial r} (r A_\theta) - \frac{\partial A_r}{\partial \theta}\right)$$
As both components vanishes, $A_r = 0 = A_\theta$, my initial "guess" was correct.

**My point is: If you don't have the intuition about the solution, sit down and calculate.** If you are not interested in the actual quantitive result, the calculation is not too difficult and it is worth learning how to express vectors or the curl in different coordinates.